# Allow multiple values in custom fields for activities?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, activities, admin

It is of utmost importance to our organization to allow multiple registrations in a custom field specifically for new **activities**.

It seems that custom field groups that allow multiple records are only allowed for contact use.

Is there any possibility to achieve this?

[image]

[image]

WordPress

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want.  Could you add an example or screenshots?

Comment: Also do not understand. Usually Activities are 'connected' to contacts based on one of the Activity Contact options (created by, with, assigned to). are you trying to do something else, eg have a multiple results field for 'contact reference'

Comment: @Aidan Sorry, I updated my post to explain it better.

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Sorry, I updated my post to explain it better.

Comment: Responding to the updated question - yes contacts can have them, but not activities. It's a known limitation.